# projecting points onto the sky

Tags: math, graphics, 3d

If I had a sphere with unit radius, and I had some points defined as latitudes and longitudes on that sphere, and I had a camera defined with a vertical and horizontal field of view angle which is always in the centre of the sphere. How can I project these points onto that camera?

Comment: what camera projection do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point at direction (x,y,z) at infinity has homogeneous coordinates of (x,y,z,0). So assuming that you use a typical view-projection matrices to describe your camera model, it is as simple as calculating

```
P * V * ( cos(lon)*cos(lat), sin(lon)*cos(lat), sin(lat), 0 )'
```

and then proceeding with a perspective divide and rasterization.

Comment: I was going to try and avoid using matrices but I have realised that was quite stupid and was going to make things very difficult so this is the best possible answer. thankyou

Comment: @DalyBarron: you can do the same without matrices. E.g. V can be replaced with a quaternion, and P by a direct scaling and swizzling. That really depends on how  the rest of your code is structured. If the projection you want is not rectilinear then the math will change again... but you need to explain what's the exact projection you're trying to do and the framework you're working in.